# Change button border thickness in wpf?

Tags: .net, wpf, button, border, thickness

Why the border thickness of the Button doesn't change?

If I change the border thickness to 1 or 100, it doesn't matters. It's the same. I would like to change it using **Style**, not **Custom Template**.

```
 <Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="newYellowButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" SpreadMethod="Pad" ColorInterpolationMode="SRgbLinearInterpolation">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEE3B" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0E49A" Offset="1" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="9"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-4"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource newYellowButton}" Content="Ok"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: works fine for me, the code you've posted. Also tried changing BorderThickness in the Style and output is as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by changing the [Button's ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Copy those style, brushes and ... to you resource dictionary then change the values you want.

To change the border thickness find the following code and make changes you want:

```
...
<Border 
      x:Name="Border"  
      CornerRadius="2" 
      BorderThickness="1"                             //CHANGE THIS VALUE
      Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
      <ContentPresenter 
        Margin="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
</Border>
...
```

Comment: I was just wondering if this can be achieved without template, just with style.

Comment: Actually if you follow the link you will find out that, this is a simple style. I edited my post.