# Change Border Thickness by Xaml, `wpf`

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Please keep in mind i am new with `WPF`, I am trying to give my `Button` a `border thickness` value via `.Xaml templates`, However, its not working, Here is my `.Xaml`:

```
    <Button>
      <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF01F1F" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF01F1F" />
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
              <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> 
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                     </Border> 
                   </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF01F1F" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
       </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Thanks in Advance.

**Update:::**

I have tried the [Change Thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636160/change-button-border-thickness-in-wpf) answer, however now it disables my `IsMouseOver` property,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your own custom template which doesn't use the BorderThickness property of the button itself, so it should be:

```
  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Border>
```

Or you can set it to 5 directly on the template.