# Basic WPF ToggleButton Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I require a toggle button that has not border when `IsChecked = False` and has a simple 1pt border of a certain color when `IsChecked = True`. I have the following style but my border when the button `IsChecked = True` is being set to `Transparent` (using Snoop to inspect)

```
<Style x:Key="InfoToggleButton"
         TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEF2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border CornerRadius="0" 
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007ACC"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The button works and displays properly, but when I check/click it, the border does not get displayed.

I implement this style like

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
    Style="{StaticResource InfoToggleButton}" 
    IsChecked="{Binding IsDisplayingBetInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Content="{Binding BetInfoIconSource}"/>
```

How can I get a simple toggle button with border?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I found a pretty simple covering of setting button borders, [give this a shot and tell me how it fairs.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636160/change-button-border-thickness-in-wpf)

Comment: how did you know that it is **working** and displaying properly?

Comment: @Killercam The checked event is not firing it seems. I tested with a separate button which showed the state of the toggle button and it returned false everytime

Comment: @Killercam I've copied and applied your style to `ToggleButton` and it seems to work. Bluish border appear/disappear when checked/unchecked

Comment: @Killercam did you try adding `<Border ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">`? You set `Background` but don't bind it in template and without that `Border` itself won't be hit test visible

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the problem and the solution but don't exactly know why it happens.
**Problem:** Some value other than `{x:Null}` must be set as the content of the toggle button.
**Solution:** However, a blank string can be set as the content.
**My reasoning:**  When no content is set, the ContentPresenter is **null** and thus cannot be clicked.

The problem can be solved by setting the default content to `""` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="InfoToggleButton"
     TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEF2"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" 
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007ACC"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I had the same wrong assumption that the Background should not be transparent to be clickable. In fact the Background just need to be ***non-null***. The default value of Background is ***null*** - which is transparent with mouse events. Explicitly setting the Background to `Transparent` can still help it capture mouse events normally. Just try it yourself.

Comment: @KingKing I too figured out that it just needs to be non null (see edit summaries) but trying out dkozl's suggestion, i thought that it was the transparent background of the button so i edited my answer to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign a name at the Border tag like in this way

`<Border x:Name="MyBorderName"...`

then the you have to assign the TargetName at the property.
Example

```
<Setter TargetName="MyBorderName" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007ACC"/>
<Setter TargetName="MyBorderName" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
```

Otherwise WPF does not know who to assign the Property BorderBrush and BorderThickness